# Bmp image manipulation

Tags: arrays, vb.net, matrix, bmp

What is the procedure to follow in order to have a bmp image ready to be manipulated and in order to be able to perform aritmethic operations with them?

For example, if I have `image1.bmp` and `image2.bmp` and I want to get some kind of correction factor so I would need to perform operations such as

`mean(image1/image2)*image1`

The only thing I can think of is to put somehow the images inside an array, but I don't get to understand how to load the image and put it into an array.

Would it be an array? or a matrix?.

Would appreciate any help aboput this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my stab at it. Hope it helps.

```
Sub Main(filePath1 As String, filePath2 As String, filePath3 As String)

    Dim bmpImage1 As New Drawing.Bitmap(filePath1)
    Dim bmpImage2 As New Drawing.Bitmap(filePath2)
    Dim bmpImage3 As New Drawing.Bitmap(filePath3)

    Dim resultBmpImage As New Drawing.Bitmap(bmpImage1.Width, bmpImage1.Height)

    'Iterate through every pixel:
    For x As Integer = 0 To bmpImage1.Width - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To bmpImage1.Height - 1
            Dim processedColor As System.Drawing.Color =
                ProcessColor(
                    bmpImage1.GetPixel(x, y),
                    bmpImage2.GetPixel(x, y),
                    bmpImage3.GetPixel(x, y))
            resultBmpImage.SetPixel(x, y, processedColor)
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Private Function ProcessColor(
                             color1 As System.Drawing.Color,
                             color2 As System.Drawing.Color,
                             color3 As System.Drawing.Color) As System.Drawing.Color
    Dim resultGrayLevel As Integer = (color1.R / color2.R) + color3.R
    Dim color As System.Drawing.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, resultGrayLevel, resultGrayLevel, resultGrayLevel)
    Return color
End Function
```

The thing is: if we are not talking about grayscale colors (that is: a color in which R=G=B), I don't know if certain operations will make sense... I don't know enough about image processing to answer that.

Comment: Hi Xavier, thanks for your answer and yes the image is greyscale not a color image

Comment: In this case it should be relatively easy, since you can just pick one of the three components (R, G or B), perform the operation, and replicate it once again as RGB. Hope my code was helpful and if so please don't forget to mark it as answered. If you have any questions please tell me and I'll try to help.

Comment: Hi Xavier, you code helps a bit, however it is not clear yet how to modificate the pixels and create a new bmp image.

Comment: Edited my post with a closer version of the exact code you should be using.

Comment: Thanks, that might help!